# Extend a class/widget by functionality in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have an Widget that expands the functionality of an existing Widget.
Example: I want an `"ResponisveText`"-Widget. It should have the exact same properties as the existing `Text`-Widget but with the difference that the fontSize is handled different here.

How can I create such an Widget in an clean way, so that I have access to the fontSize etc.?

Before, I did it like this, but I think there's a better way:

```
Text('foo', style: Font.body1.copyWith(fontSize: responsiveFontSize(Font.body1.fontSize))
```

I want It to be like this:

```
ResponsiveText('foo', style: Font.body1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve what you want by extending the `Text` widget, and then instead of using directly the `style` property, you declare a new `style` parameter, that before assigning its value to the `super.style` parameter, you can manipulate your `fontSize` value as you wish.

```
class ResponsiveText extends Text {

  ResponsiveText(
    super.data,
    {
      TextStyle? style,
      super.strutStyle,
      super.textAlign,
      super.textDirection,
      super.locale,
      super.softWrap,
      super.overflow,
      super.textScaleFactor,
      super.maxLines,
      super.semanticsLabel,
      super.textWidthBasis,
      super.textHeightBehavior,
      super.selectionColor,
    }
  ) : super(style: _handleFontSize(style));

  static TextStyle? _handleFontSize(TextStyle? style) {
    return style?.copyWith(
      fontSize: responsiveFontSize(style.fontSize)
    );
  }

  static double? responsiveFontSize(double? fontSize) {
    // do stuff here to your font size
    return fontSize;
  }
}
```

let me know if you have any question

Answer (score -1):

That would be my solution:

```
class ResponsiveText extends StatelessWidget {
       ResponsiveText({super.key, required this.textToDisplay});
       final String textToDisplay;
    
      final List fonts = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fonts.addAll([
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
      Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
      ]);
    return Text(textToDisplay, style: fonts[Random().nextInt(6)],);
  }
}
```

You utilize native headline (or other ThemeOfContext) parameters that you can modify by hand in the file that handles app ui.